# sap.m.UploadCollection Drag and Drop issue sapui5 1.52.9

Tags: file-upload, sapui5, sap-fiori

We have been using the control sap.m.UploadCollection since SAPUI5 version 1.44.24.  We are using the control with the property instantUpload="false".  On the change event we use the following code to add the x-csrf-token as a header parameter and it’s working:

```
var oModel = this.getView().getModel();
var oUploadCollection = oEvent.getSource();
oModel.refreshSecurityToken();
var oHeaders = oModel.oHeaders;
var sToken = oHeaders['x-csrf-token'];
// Header Token
var oCustomerHeaderToken = new sap.m.UploadCollectionParameter({
    name: "x-csrf-token",
    value: sToken
    });
oUploadCollection._oFileUploader.setUploadUrl(url);
oUploadCollection.addHeaderParameter(oCustomerHeaderToken);
```

Now we upgraded our SAPUI5 to 1.52.9 and the Drag and Drop feature seemed to have been added to the control.  If we don’t use the Drag and Drop feature everything works fine.  Now if we use the Drag and Drop feature, the header parameter get added on the change event.

The problem is now that I am getting a 405 (Method not allowed) when calling the upload method, which we call manually since the instantUpload is set to false.

When I debug the upload method it seems the header parameter is lost or not present inside the FileUploader-dbg.js controller, the header parameter is not present in aRequestHeaders array.  If I debug a “regular” file being added without the Drag and Drop feature, the header parameter is set inside the aRequestHeaders array.  Any help on this issue?

The first image shows the issue I have with the parameter not being there: [Drag and Drop Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcGee.jpg).

The second image shows a working scenario: [Working Scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itep9.jpg).

The xml view looks like:

```
<form:content>
<UploadCollection id="UploadCollection" maximumFilenameLength="155" multiple="false" change="onChange" instantUpload="false" fileDeleted="onFileDeleted" filenameLengthExceed="onFileNameExceed" fileSizeExceed="onFileSizeExceed" typeMissmatch="onTypeMissmatch"
uploadComplete="onUploadComplete" beforeUploadStarts="onBeforeUploadStarts" selectionChange="onSelectionChange"                                 uploadTerminated="onUploadTerminated" noDataText="{i18n>textnoAttachment_Invoice}" mimeType="application/pdf" fileType="pdf, PDF">
</UploadCollection>
</form:content>
```

The controller, based on a successful OData call, looks like:

```
_onCreateSuccess: function(oCheckIn) {

    var oModelControlsUI = this.getView().getModel("controlsUI");
    oModelControlsUI.setProperty("/buttonSubmitEnable", false);
    oModelControlsUI.setProperty("/buttonCancelEnable", false);
    var sId = oCheckIn.WiId;
    var oModel = this.getModel();
    var BindingContext = this.getView().getBindingContext();
    var objectView = BindingContext.getObject();
    objectView.WiId = sId;
    this._sId = sId;

    // Create a new entry in the Model with the newly created entry         
    var oFormInfoContext = oModel.createEntry("/CheckInProcSet", {
        properties: objectView
    });

    //Bind the element to the view not just the form
    this.getView().setBindingContext(oFormInfoContext);
    oModel.refresh();

    //Upload the attachment
    var oCollection = this.getView().byId("UploadCollection");
    oCollection.upload();

}
```

The onBeforeUploadStarts method looks like:

```
        onBeforeUploadStarts: function(oEvent) {
            // Header Slug
            // Add additional parameter
            //          Get the Model for the form 
            var oModel = this.getModel();
            this.getView().setModel(oModel);
            var BindingContext = this.getView().getBindingContext();
            var objectView = BindingContext.getObject();
            var workitemID = objectView.WiId;
            var doctype = objectView.Ncitype;

            var oCustomerHeaderSlug = new sap.m.UploadCollectionParameter({
                name: "slug",
                value: oEvent.getParameter("fileName") + "|" + workitemID + "|" + doctype
            });

            oEvent.getParameters().addHeaderParameter(oCustomerHeaderSlug);
            // Request the returned entity in JSON format so that we can insert
            // the uploaded file into the upload collection for display
            oEvent.getParameters().addHeaderParameter(new sap.m.UploadCollectionParameter({

                name: "accept",
                value: "application/json"
            }));
},
```

Let me know if you need more information.

Thank you

Comment: Thanks for the piece of code and images. To see how you use sap.m.UploadCollection it would be useful if could you please post all relevant coding (controller, …). Maybe you could build a working sample in a tool like https://plnkr.co/? I think this might be useful to help to debug the issue.

Comment: Hi, I added some coding details... Thank you

Answer (score 0):

this was an issue which was reported on GitHub ([GitHub issue 2199](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2199)).  The asnwer is in GitHub, but basically:

SAP has suggested us to use beforefileuploadStart event instead of change
event to set the header parameter. This is working. Some limitations with
this method also. oEvent object doesn't have filedetails information for
example filesize, uploaded time etc. It has only filename.

Thank you
Jn